# What is the interface protocol between a compute-engine VM instance and a cloud-storage bucket (public/private IP)?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine

I'm creating a new compute-engine VM using the *node.js* method-
`zone.createVM(name, config)`
That VM is going to upload files to a cloud-storage bucket using the *python* method-
`blob.upload_from_filename(src)`
My bucket **Location Type** is **Multi-region**.
 
My VM **zone** is **us-central1-a**
Do I need to set the **http/https** fields of the `zone.createVM` **config** parameter to **true**?
What is the interface between the VM and the bucket?
Does it matter if they are in the same region?
Does that effect the billing on data transfer between the vm and the bucket?

Couldn't find any documentation on this.

Creating the VM with node.js:

```
const config = {
   os: 'ubuntu',
   http: true,
   https: true
};
const data = await zone.createVM(name, config);
const operation = data[1];
await operation.promise();
// Virtual machine created
```

Upload from VM to bucket with python:

```
bucket = storage_client.get_bucket()
blob = bucket.blob(dstPath)
blob.upload_from_filename(srcPath)
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I need to set the http/https fields of the zone.createVM config
>   parameter to true?

Only if your VM instance is running a web server or a process responding to HTTP/HTTPS requests. This setting is not related to making Google API requests to Cloud Storage.

> What is the interface between the VM and the bucket?

Depends on what you mean by an interface. Requests to Cloud Storage using the HTTP/HTTPS protocol. Google publishes the REST API for Cloud Storage.

[APIs & Reference](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/apis)

> Does it matter if they are in the same region?

From a technology implementation viewpoint, No. From a performance viewpoint, yes as performance is typically higher the closer communicating systems are. From a financial viewpoint, yes.

> Does that effect the billing on data transfer between the vm and the
>   bucket?

Yes. Google charges for data traffic between different zones/regions. Google Cloud pricing is not simple with many factors to consider, refer to the documentation.

[Network Pricing](https://cloud.google.com/compute/network-pricing)

Comment: @Dan - don't forget to select the answer.

Comment: What do you mean 'select the answer'? Vote it up?

Comment: Yes, vote it up and select the checkmark. Questions and answers get votes plus a checkmark for the correct answer.